# Retrieve data from string type value

Tags: c#, string

I have this segment code:

```
string responseFromServer; 
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

responseFromServer is a string type variable, contains this "key:value" data:

```
{"refresh_token":"69d2b7bq95b6sf5b64c55240ed563a52","expires_in":86400,"access_token":"0q761ee1897hd50u2r4fec80f333dd43","token_type":"bearer","x_mailru_vid":"13090076762971691053"}
```

This string I need to convert to this string array:

```
refresh_token = 69d2b7bq95b6sf5b64c55240ed563a52
expires_in = 86400
access_token = 0q761ee1897hd50u2r4fec80f333dd43
token_type = bearer
x_mailru_vid = 13090076762971691053
```

What is the easiest way to implement it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a json string. You can use any json serializer. I'll use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);  


public class Result
{
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string x_mailru_vid { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize to a dictionary too.

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Another alternative with built-in JavaScriptSerializer

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```